# Ordenar imágenes con distintas proporciones en galería LightGallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buen día, estoy trabajando con la librería LightGallery. El problema que tengo es cuando las imágenes no tienen las mismas dimensiones o posición, ya que la librería las ajusta a como considera deben ordenarse. En el ejemplo que agrego, coloqué una imagen vertical y las demás imágenes horizontales y más pequeñas para que pueda notarse mejor el ordenamiento, que no se ve nada bien.

[image: gallery1]

En cambio cuando las imágenes tienen las mismas dimensiones y posición si queda bien ordenada la galería.

[image: Gallery2]

Me podrían ayudar, indicándome que puedo hacer cuando las imágenes tienen diferentes tamaños y posición, para poder ordenar mejor la galería no importando la imagen que suban.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Link para JsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/raintrooper/c8s3rtfq/12/

```js
  $('#lightgallery').lightGallery();
```

```css
     body {
       background-color: #152836
     }

     .demo-gallery>ul {
       margin-bottom: 0;
     }

     .demo-gallery>ul>li {
       float: left;
       margin-bottom: 15px;
       margin-right: 20px;
       width: 200px;
     }

     .demo-gallery>ul>li a {
       border: 3px solid #FFF;
       border-radius: 3px;
       display: block;
       overflow: hidden;
       position: relative;
       float: left;
     }

     .demo-gallery>ul>li a>img {
       -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
       -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
       transition: transform 0.15s ease 0s;
       -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
       transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
     }

     .demo-gallery>ul>li a:hover>img {
       -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
       transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
     }

     .demo-gallery>ul>li a:hover .demo-gallery-poster>img {
       opacity: 1;
     }

     .demo-gallery>ul>li a .demo-gallery-poster {
       background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       position: absolute;
       right: 0;
       top: 0;
       -webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
       -o-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
       transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
     }

     .demo-gallery>ul>li a .demo-gallery-poster>img {
       left: 50%;
       margin-left: -10px;
       margin-top: -10px;
       opacity: 0;
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
       transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
     }

     .demo-gallery>ul>li a:hover .demo-gallery-poster {
       background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     }

     .demo-gallery .justified-gallery>a>img {
       -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
       -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
       transition: transform 0.15s ease 0s;
       -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
       transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
     }

     .demo-gallery .justified-gallery>a:hover>img {
       -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
       transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
     }

     .demo-gallery .justified-gallery>a:hover .demo-gallery-poster>img {
       opacity: 1;
     }

     .demo-gallery .justified-gallery>a .demo-gallery-poster {
       background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       position: absolute;
       right: 0;
       top: 0;
       -webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
       -o-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
       transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
     }

     .demo-gallery .justified-gallery>a .demo-gallery-poster>img {
       left: 50%;
       margin-left: -10px;
       margin-top: -10px;
       opacity: 0;
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
       transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
     }

     .demo-gallery .justified-gallery>a:hover .demo-gallery-poster {
       background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     }

     .demo-gallery .video .demo-gallery-poster img {
       height: 48px;
       margin-left: -24px;
       margin-top: -24px;
       opacity: 0.8;
       width: 48px;
     }

     .demo-gallery.dark>ul>li a {
       border: 3px solid #04070a;
     }

     .home .demo-gallery {
       padding-bottom: 80px;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.11/js/lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/picturefill/2.3.1/picturefill.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.11/css/lightgallery.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="demo-gallery">
  <ul id="lightgallery" class="list-unstyled row">
    <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3" data-responsive="img/2-375.jpg 375, img/2-480.jpg 480, img/2.jpg 800" data-src="img/2-1600.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Bowness Bay</h4><p>A beautiful Sunrise this morning taken En-route to Keswick not one as planned but I'm extremely happy I was passing the right place at the right time....</p>">
      <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3" data-responsive="img/13-375.jpg 375, img/13-480.jpg 480, img/13.jpg 800" data-src="img/13-1600.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Bowness Bay</h4><p>A beautiful Sunrise this morning taken En-route to Keswick not one as planned but I'm extremely happy I was passing the right place at the right time....</p>">
      <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3" data-responsive="img/4-375.jpg 375, img/4-480.jpg 480, img/4.jpg 800" data-src="img/4-1600.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Bowness Bay</h4><p>A beautiful Sunrise this morning taken En-route to Keswick not one as planned but I'm extremely happy I was passing the right place at the right time....</p>">
      <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxMTEhUTEhMWFhUVFxcVFRUYGBUVFxcXFRUWFhcVFRUYHSggGBolHRUVITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMtNygtLisBCgoKDg0OFxAQGi0lHx0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tKy0tLS0tLS0tLf/AABEIARYAtQMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAABBQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAECAwUGBwj/xABAEAABAwMBBAcGBAQEBwEAAAABAAIRAwQhMQUSQVEGEyJhcYGRMlKhscHwBxTR4SMzQvFigpLCFUNyk6KjwyT/xAAYAQADAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBP/EACERAQEAAgICAwEBAQAAAAAAAAABAhESIQMxE0FRYSIE/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD1frBzCiXDmq55BvqmNQ82rp4suSwbvL4FTG6OHwVLXu94Ji4+/wDJGhyEb3cok9yHL/8AEVEuPMomJc1/Wn3U/XO934ob19Ut0fZVcYnnRIrO90eqbr3ch6qiByCQ8AjjByq413ch81bbXhBhwQu8U0FHGDnW/TfIQW0mmCQdFVYOMgLUqMkGQsL/AJybS8o5w1H8/kkK7kRc0YKrDF0Syxz2WVHrnqJqP+4R9vYbzd6R3DX1UGWuYdAHNTyxVxyAElRdKNqUSCR9E9K3J4qucLjQ1Gwc4Tw5lPWtN3QyeOFthkMDeQVLgIOFl8t20+KaYjaRPBJaYeAkr+S/hfHP0FuJ9xXwE8dyfJHEPuJ+rREdyUFLkfEP1afqlfulLdRyHFT1Sfq1ZuJbqOQ4obifcClupQlsaR3QibWiCchQp0iUczUQpyyXjispsDdAk6orH6IZxWXtoT6bSDIQDqeYR5UG0syql0mzYiozAA4ckHUlE1KiGeUoqqy8ymou7Wcyme5V06sHRXpI/rJQdR5Ti67kz2k6JSaFqktSRNGkTKSvknigAklCcMSPRkgpEQm6yNEAySgapTGqU9FuLCEkNJ5qdNrnGBqU9FsVb0t493FFutm8FK0obrY48UnrK3tpJ0oc6DCtpnKiPBMWpGue6VWU28kSgESqhUUiq3NThE98qkhTKiVUJElVOdCsUKjcqoVWU6clHADgELasRrGQVGVVDNpJK9Mo2piyU7XKbaRPtSradNsjitrYykqsOKr3STx9Ea6kAdFZImVPJXEB1DuRVzLTuKKHik56XKjjFf5dg4IikGjQASqSZSU+zWudnBwoOcoFVlyNHsQamFQ56iKiZzk9FtMOTgqsBTIQEi9VvclCi6UyQcUxCTioymS5tLvV1Oi3xKGaFdTlKnBIaJkKYKpYrYUKTCSiEkGodTjkqw770VdarPGPBRZVHmq0lc58HKi25BMRKoqEO1PopCq0Y4feqei2k+4iYCFq3hiIIV5h2n7Ke6IgpzUAa1ujOZhaTHAhDh7W6BM65J00SvYnS6oqnFMQTx9CrKdE8Sj0apRJRTqHmfT4qg0xx1RstGtWHegERxQOw9stuLi6pN9mgaYB97eD94+EthR6Q7T6mi8iASCMfFcR+E14417o+81hz/1O/VPjuWlvVkeoOYmNKQmDnHVIawpUodRPBSp0OZRGirdVRujRuq71MAc1Sasp3PxICAIY5WArNNYq+jVPMIsGxkpKjrElOjQZRGuvkk+2JyPohrCtvcZ8kaah5EKruUpqhKtqWjJE+CHFs45ELQqVVTXrRzTlpWRVRpEA7x04aqD2P/sn/MNwSouuPE+CrsjsZ3T4oqm1vJDtceA+/FEMZGSc9yVOHNVoUvzIUGtDsq0UmqejVVb5uh0WfcbROQAVohgOn0QN/VAa7ezGirHRXbhenu0D1cTEoL8IiN+4P+GmPUvP0WL01vN58T3+ui2vwrtSW1jDt1zgN8FuC0E7u6cn29Qtr6Z/b0s3nenFcnQyq6VqwATLvE/QKVe0n2SW4wBosul9ndXVfXDmEDX2bXA/mT8/QaoMWD5MyRzkD5q5hj+puV/G+y5aM7w9VCretOjh6rnby0cyJMjxlBq54Ze9pvks606c3DPfHqpU7+kNHZXKyn3lfwT9L5K6Z+1mTr80lzW8kj4MR8ldzQZujs6JqlXKc5HFUkieOi4260NkIG6oO7ydAi6VWTg/qraQwS5OXQ1sA3Zh3RvQOJiT+wWla02Nb2Qq610IiFEVd0ZRbaJJDvceYhVPrgIhoBEkZQlxRxMIgqDapOuFfQcTq5BATwzyVjYY0knJ+CdhQcyoBxXL9KtotaRSBO+5peRyaMCe8lw+ytKvdNYx73zusaS7dnejujivMtqbSZUfWrMO92d3fO+0nfhwbuOPZgbumDIwIy5Oyt6crti6L6ruc/JenfhqBTsQT/XUe70hn+xeUNdO+fAepn/avSujF3UZa06ZawANlpBJJD+3LpA3TLjgT4rbjyume9OvftIA7oOVW/bUYMghYn5nuyoPeXGSVc8U+0866CttgFgJJ3lmv2mf7rOUgwnxKuePGFc7RNxtBz9YjkMKjfRdDY9RwJAgj+k6meSduxa0E7kAcyJPgE5lhOtlrKg95SCIpbLqkwGGVqUOjxI7Ti08onCWXkxn2cwtYoakusbsikAAG+ZyT6pLP54v46LLiRgeaj+VnV3os/8AMmCS8N5DB9VOltKRg+JiPRc3GtdwWKbWSck9wTW1QuEukfBZF1td8wz9/JC0NqVGk74MeH6q/jtieUdE6uxpiP1KpqMe8kkwOHNUUL8O1bA4EwqLza7G4nKmY3Z2xqC4AESq690CFzD7+ZMlN+ZLve8gtJ4k8xtxeFpMFUsui8x7Tu8oFwMyQd30+CLp3LYhrRPgPmtOMiNhulFuX0DTNbqnF4cXCYgY3TkY148F5o6h1FqGTJdUeSTqe0c/JehdItqNo0muLXuJIAa10Oj3onIElcBt90CJlzWn1P7uUelMRoMn5ffiV6pZNimwDgxuoIOgGQdF5VYdtzRxLgPUwvc22LdAPkqxy0mxGwphzSOqDuMxB5YMoqwsKDwcZB0k4HeE7LSJInPeVaapZoB3qblb6VJPsT/wOjxB8ZP9lJuxKcgjh98FGwuy50EGIWsBGiyuWU+1yY1UykRpCfdPFXFxSDAfFZrRoCDKhcvzhT3Oai6AgBHCpJgD+6Su30lWy05VlhBEPzq79u7vRt24NaDv6co1VlakBENgAY14lBsotDstmTqcegW+9+2WtKgHGS17slSbs7eGXunvMrQqhjQCxoxygevNCm8eRAYBJ5/eUTK30NfqivQEQ12nBCusgB2na8Yn6rVtqUieJ18uaFv7Go849AP0VTLvWysUUbcAiSPnpxjgi7mtjAnwB+whLOweHSZ8JW+bbAPwSyykpyMCvYPJ7jw1PgrGbNiJxzyth2PFD1AXFEztHFyvS/YtNxoVCSX03mNI3R2yCI5tGccV5/tZ287GZM4z7I/f4L13a9v/AASSNMifT5FeR7be0PbAguc//S2IPm5zx/lUGF6O0Zu6TRxrM9C4Fe6A814x0Zb/APuoEDG9JPAbvP1PovXy5OEMbUTGDqEE15nmjwZCLNGutHQcLRp1ZWMHEa45K1tYjis8sVStyJCiGkIG2u0Sa0rOzS0qhwVXqE1e4EKhl1OichL+rSVYrJJ9gLcVYGdOXFVXW6WxjI4oC53yZa5scoysutUqA5MccLbHDbO5I3F0dCMDxB11RFvcB47U+JOnFAMeCZfvH4/NGWdPeOsA4j64Wtk0iOgs6ohkEQY+SNfWAmFkssCI7RMacEZTZzC5spGsQewnSUXRqYgqsNMqt+Eex6GsDVF4CCFRQ60o4jYfb0OpuJLuy06EhpmB2gMO7p0XjXSu2a2pSdBDurAMz/VUqP08XekL2W67bHA+yRnwXkHT4k3LgODWgcoDRP1VFUuiNMm8oSNXEjvAY7I9F6m/wXl34fuNS9ocBTDjDZHs0erE50gNEaY0XslO0NQkAAeKcy17LQWhSkTCIGAnuWmkYJlvPRQpVQ4wEW77PSNVU7+7x8kdVt44rPuqZHeiWUrETeDnCR2vBAkLKvbcgST5LPcIHf5rWYSp5WOkudrYHfChS2rOmOc/Rc46u4ZOcQq31yU/ig512TtpM5plydF7joCUkvih867cWjZmE5sWO1APermlTLwFz7rTQRmzWAyBwhXW9m1kkBXNqBJ1UJbo1DhimYQ7q6m12Egi5ybq5yndhV9aQmDNtxOSlVp8jhVvrg8Cna/OU+yU3lPskcCDK8j6fW8ViGDFOi0HMQOzJP8A3F7JWgtcvKOl1y0Vbh4guaWsjlIEenVgo2bF/DuiTe0eXWNnJGGh1Q+PsL6At6ojHBeLfhfaB9YO90VHA/8AS1jP/sV6cL/qzBBPeEa2J01L6gXDhqEBTY5jiC0d0cULU2o46Tg8o+aattWRnB8QqmN9FbBla9A1KxtobQB4rN2peODok9yy31idStcfGi5D7q5DtCoMJ0mQPuVnb6Ktq8a6LXWkbH0rAuK0rXYQ4mULa7QC0mbVbxKyyuX0uSCRs1o0STMvg7IKSz/0roSKqrr3YmJysivtQNHf8VmXG0p0CqePZXJ1VOuDq5U1Lts6krnra8H9SM61rTM+SOGi5Nq3vATAUby6eNNFlG5bqCB3pO2gzmSY8cpcD21qVxxLpVgu1lULvHsk/RW1qoI00KXE9tNtQnwVohYzawjVEUrlpGTBSuJ7H1j2SvCNuXs1Lwe9ckf6DVAXtfXz5L54vrgnfPv1Xv785HzKnQem/hf2WudyYP8A2Pd9KTV2VxdBcJ0DduW7pPFrfRgPpLytS5v+9aYYdFlkPu7/AO8rNrXhPNBvrkqLHLbWme9iJJ4kqxlo5xgLT2LYb5E8TAXd3eyqVO3eA0SW68Vz5/8ARq6jfHxetvJntymFRad3bhpIhZ1RmV045bY5Y6SFwradwO9COYoyq6qGp+fITrL6xJHGDYo+KkHgIbeOUwKCEtr6pw9zlFlu49wRlK1IzB9ErYeqnSt3QJRzWho9kD5ocXEYg+qrfWJUe1jOs4hRfcuOAhW1OaVbalGnPWODYjB1Miey0ZKQGMqVAD2dcTIyh7++pW4mtUAPujJPgNSuX2r0te+W27dwab7oLvIaN+PkuaeCTvOcXOOpJJJ8SclTcjek7I231tvcVgC1rN8Nk5O5T3yTGmoXi9XQBeoWpDNk1iP6qdb1ceqXmdGmXVabfec0eW9n6rP3Veno9K4Ipsbya0egCqNRQcVWXLsk0wt2vFThzV9HVAgrRtSGDeOTwCnPqLw9uv6FUy6uA72WDe8+C0+l/SAB3VMMge0Rz5LJ2Rc9TaVKv9dTTw0ELkqvWOlxB1klcWPj55231HVllxkHvrklbOw9ida7dK5SjcQQeS9C6EVN1j7iqYboPqVfm3jj0jx6yB9KOjzaFMbhmTk8ccFxNVsLrukvSYVzDcNGn6rkq1SVfg5Sdp8ulMpJikurbnatZknI+CupWLdZMq6rbE6A+attbRwWO2mk6VvxWhRYIVTQAracBRaqE+myNAqDbtP9MIl9UcgqarxwSAf8m0aYXD9I9n1n3lR1Oi97d1gDg3smGDQ85ldzXqhrS4nABOTjAnPJYl90qpNH8L+IeBHs+M8Rpp6ovY9OMq2NwBmjUAAOSx0acTEIPqjq90Dlj7CN21t2rVc0F4gyd04bAjRo454n1WdXqEtzEmBgiNe9LQdRYVy+xrsLgaYNFjPOo6o/PEy1cxsC3D70e7TaT/4/q4Lf2YALJlPjWuNRwaxjZMDX+afRWfh3s5/8W5c3+ZDWTxAPad4SGx4JY+xfQ+rbjhKGdTIXUutweAnwVLNmg6hdEzZ8WDQtXHMLQtrEveGwRnM8uK132Ya3B++9W7MbBc5wjGFOWf2rHFfd7oAYMAAY8FnbRP8ADdHHCm+sTzyeCz9t1nMDW6TJ8FOM0rK7CbL2c+tVFNvmeQGpXQdJdo7lMW9LQCDHL91PZTBaWxrP/mVR2e5hE/Fc1Wut4lxOqVnPL+Q5eGP9oc73IqBKNp0y/RW/kY1W22TOa1JE16YEQknstOv60cvUqXWnuWf1zAmN037wsNNR4MnUeiRcsv8AO8spzcToB6I0NjH1gEI+tnH1Qta6PchH35CqQrV20zUdSqtaJLqb2gY1LSAMrkbPYlZjR/DMhobqMQ0tPH/E74cguhdfKxtc6zhFw2Jl1pytbYtSZNJ5PhOPJV/8NqD/AJTxH+Bw+i7qhcAjPBSdXAGuvNTwDkKIcDSbBG4KkAiO0Q8zn/L6LtdnWzaFFlFmQxsAk68zIGpMnzWbcEPLT7rseBEFPWuXAwjHHsbbVB5OohXVKkLGp7RxCupXQcclVobWVahJga8kVdVw1gnXRNa0TPWcGz8lhV7s1Hk8OHcnrZb00KFy7wSNo6tWax+gAedPZ/dZTq7pW3dPNtbEu/m1DHeBGB5Qiz8G4zOkO0DVqbjfZb2QPDCptbGSJCFsKgnOq3qJESn66L320ba3Y1ugQt1TBVdS+ws652lCmSqtgW8w6JTIavdAlOtpGY0XUqynn+6zaVx3ItlUdyixWxgLQl1wjCBfcCVU+5nRLQ2JrVOaGf4od1ZV9YqkK1ZoiKdYaaIIlLeTIY2p3qL7jvQfWlVmojQ2PbcwJ8vv0VbrwoMvUZRotiHXBVlq9xc1oPtED1KDldB0WtZ3nkSBgHkRmfkmI1NoXZoUmsBmS4Ern6NUc1f0nr9sMBwAD55WRTJJganCWj26fo1s8VqpLvYpwXd54D6oHpRtI1qzs9lpIHkYla1yTaWfVz/EquJxrGPouNe+UpO9i1Nr4WhbXhWTKkx8KrCla11dSs2pUJTGsVVKJNC1PeSUJSVEua5SdVKpcoqTXGseagaqpToCwPKtY8c0LvppT0Bbqqr3lUHKQSCT3KEpnlRJTJYHJSqwU8oC+3pF7g0akwuhdUdb0d0Hx7yUN0OoB1Yudo1s+Zx+qF6Q3W9VLZw3HzSMFd3Be4uPH6BdP0O2M1wNapo32fLiuYsbY1HtY3iQPATqvRNpvbb2b6bDBazd784Syv0I4rpHtE1ars4BIb4LI3kzimlUScpSoSlKAnKUqMppQEpSUJTphbTKmXxwSSUqUvdKiSkkmDJJJIB2q6oxJJKhQmSSTI4ThJJAdPRp9TY9Y32qh1+C5kmU6SIHV9BLftPq4O6A0DxySgOlu0DUruAkNAAjmRx+KSSX2f0wE0J0kyJIBJJAIhKEkkA0JJJJh//Z">
                    </a>
    </li>
        <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3" data-responsive="img/1-375.jpg 375, img/1-480.jpg 480, img/1.jpg 800" data-src="img/1-1600.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Fading Light</h4><p>Classic view from Rigwood Jetty on Coniston Water an old archive shot similar to an old post but a little later on.</p>">
      <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png"></a>
    </li>
        <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3" data-responsive="img/1-375.jpg 375, img/1-480.jpg 480, img/1.jpg 800" data-src="img/1-1600.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Fading Light</h4><p>Classic view from Rigwood Jetty on Coniston Water an old archive shot similar to an old post but a little later on.</p>">
      <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png"></a>
    </li>
        <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3" data-responsive="img/1-375.jpg 375, img/1-480.jpg 480, img/1.jpg 800" data-src="img/1-1600.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Fading Light</h4><p>Classic view from Rigwood Jetty on Coniston Water an old archive shot similar to an old post but a little later on.</p>">
      <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```